# How to log all Assert statements into Junit report

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit

i have a class in which i have 6 Test(using @Test annotations). Each test has some set of Assert statements. I have got a Junit html report using ANT. But this report only shows the status of the 6 tests(pass or fail). 
i want that when i click on any of the Test, it should show the status of the Assertions which were inside that test. I don't know how to log those assertions or how to modify the default HTML report.

Answer (score 0):

If your test passes, no Assertion failed. If the test fail then the report tells you at which line it failed. Hence you don't need extra logging of the assertions.

If you want to locg assertions, you have to write your own assertion library or at least wrap an existing one.